# HttpClient.SendAsync HttpException: The Client Disconnected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have an ASP.NET web API application hosted in a Windows Azure Web Role.
The purpose of this application is to proxy Http Requests to other web enabled endpoints - such as a Service Bus Relay and return their response.

On occasion our application throws an exception when sending a request with a significant (>5MB) payload. This might happen 1 in 20 requests with a large payload.

> Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. ---> System.Web.HttpException: The client disconnected.
>   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.EndRead(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.HttpBufferlessInputStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferReadCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Web.HttpException (0x800703E3): The client disconnected.    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Web.HttpBufferlessInputStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferReadCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar)<--- ; TraceSource 'w3wp.exe' event

We send these Http Requests using the System.Net.HttpClient in .NET 4.5.

```
public class ProxyController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();
    private static readonly Uri BaseUri = new Uri("http://webendpoint.com");

    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        var newUri = new Uri(BaseUri, Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery);
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, newUri)
                {
                    Content = this.Request.Content
                };

        var task = HttpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        task.Wait();
        var response = task.Result;
        return new HttpResponseMessage(response.StatusCode)
        {
            Content = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, ctx) =>
            {
                var tempStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                tempStream.CopyToAsync(stream).Wait();
                stream.Flush();
                stream.Close();
            })
        };
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this problem?

Comment: It's hard to help you debug that code as you must have written it from memory because it is full of errors.  However, the first thing I would recommend if you truly are creating just a proxy is to just use a DelegatingHandler and don't bother with an ApiController.

Comment: Fair point, I wasn't doing you any favours with that code. My Bad. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try returning a Task version, then replace the sync code with async. No more ".Results" stuff, instead use the "await" keyword and put the "asyc" keyword on your method. Something like this:

```
public class ProxyController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();
    private static readonly Uri BaseUri = new Uri("http://webendpoint.com");

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        var newUri = new Uri(BaseUri, Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery);
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, newUri)
        {
            Content = Request.Content
        };

        var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

        return new HttpResponseMessage(response.StatusCode)
        {
            Content = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, content, ctx) =>
            {
                var tempStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                await tempStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Flush();
                stream.Close();
            })
        };
    }
}
```